Sheng Ji (升级) rules for throwing cards (甩牌)
In the game Sheng Ji (升级), it is possible to lead a combination of cards when you believe they are unbeatable in their respective suits. This is called throwing cards (甩牌).
In my experience, the throwing-cards mechanism is subtle enough that new players of Sheng Ji (including myself) rarely or never use it, and there are sometimes arguments when it is used. I'm curious if there's a good description of this mechanism out there that specifically addresses irregularities like incorrect leads. House rules are also fine if they work in practice. From what I can gather, this game is not standardized, so in a certain sense all rules are house rules.
I have three questions about this combination:

Under what circumstances can a lead of thrown cards be beaten?
What happens if a lead of thrown cards does not actually consist of the highest possible cards.
Does a thrown card lead need to consist exclusively of cards of the same suit?

For 1, the question is pretty straightforward.
It seems obvious that a trick can only be beaten if someone can beat every card led. However it's still not clear what this means because Sheng Ji is a multi-trick game and it's not clear what the internal structure is of a thrown-card lead.
For example, if threes and clubs are trump (主牌) and I lead KS, QS, QS, can that be beaten with 3S, 3H, 3D?
I suspect that the answer is no and that cards within a thrown-cards play maintain their internal structure, i.e. a lead of KS, QS, QS is really a lead of KS, {QS, QS}.
For question 2, I am even more confused.
If we take Wikipedia at face value, then the penalty for an incorrect lead of thrown cards seems extremely mild.

If any card(s) in the combination may be bested by another player in the suit lead, they will be asked, by that player, to take back the cards that are the largest in the suit, and play any of the single/double/tractor cards that may be bested as penalty.

I read this as saying that any player holding a card which demonstrates that a lead is invalid may play it and force the leader to play a specific combination out of what they already played as a penalty.
This seems bad for three reasons:

It is logistically inconvenient if other players have played since the incorrect lead.
The incorrect lead still communicates information to the leader's partner.
If the partner has the card that invalidates the lead, they may simply choose not to invoke the penalty.

For example, it seems to be against the spirit of the rules but not the letter to lead an entire suit as thrown cards. In which case one of the opponents can force you to retract all but one combination of the lead. This penalty is so mild that it might be worth it to a player to communicate information about their hand to their partner, especially if they were going to lose the trick anyway.
For another point, if threes and clubs are trump, is AH, KH, KH a valid lead if hearts have not been played before? The KH-pair is unbeatable because the AH is part of the lead, but is that good enough for the purposes of determining lead validity?
For question 3, all of the examples I have seen are of thrown cards that are all the same suit. I am just wondering whether this restriction technically exists or not.
